# Cassandra OpsCenter slow query logging

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

We are using OpsCenter 5.2.4 (DSE 4.8.4. with Cassandra 2.1.12.). We are trying to pinpoint some problems and we would like to log slow queries. We tried to enable it through settings and performance. I have two issues:

1. TTL is stuck on 3600, I tried to put TTL value up and down but it always writes data with 3600s. Why is that? I tried to put threshold on 16ms so I can get fast some queries in `dse_perf.node_slow_log` and got few results, when I do query like `SELECT source_ip, TTL(source_ip) FROM dse_perf.node_slow_log;` It always returns TTL of that field 3600 even though I set it on 900 or 7200s. When I change this setting in OpsCenter I verified that value is actually changed on node in `dse.yaml` and it is but in table my data is always written with 3600s TTL.
2. Slow queries screen in OpsCenter is broken, I tried to query table as mentioned before and I have results there (15 slow queries) but when I try to see queries from OpsCenter I have one SELECT COUNT query which I do not see in tables, and none from 15 slow queries which I see when I view data from `cqlsh`. Where is data viewed on slow queries panel in OpsCenter read from?

Comment: Would you have an example of how your insert data with a TTL?

Comment: What version of cassandra or dse?

Comment: It is DSE 4.8.4. with Cassandra 2.1.12. Inserting TTL-ed data is feature of DSE and outside our control, you can just setup value of TTL and threshold in ms above which DSE will log slow queries

Answer (score 0):

1) Changing the TTL does not change the ttl of data already written. It changes the TTL of any future data written. Once a mutation is sent its written in an sstable and immutable, its there until GCed.

2) What tables are the slow queries for? Slow queries in the OpsCenter, and dse_perf keyspaces are filtered out in the UI since they are outside of your control. You can update that in the [slow_query_ignore](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-opsc/opsc/configure/agentAddressConfiguration.html?scroll=agentAddressConfiguration__slow_query_ignore) option in the agents `address.yaml`. Documented as:

> A list of keyspaces to ignore in the slow query log of the Performance Service. Default: ["OpsCenter" "dse_perf"].

They are still recorded in the table per the DSE slow query performance service, but OpsCenter will not display them.

Comment: Regarding your first answer, maybe I was not clear enough, TTL on new data is stuck on 3600, I tried to put it higher and lower and it is always 3600ms